# load file and after specific line delete all remaining lines in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external file, lets say it is called "file.html". On Button press with JavaScript or jQuery I would like to load that file, find a specific line (for example "< !--delete bellow this line-->"), delete everything after that line and save that file back to its origin.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so what is your question and where is the code you are having problems doing it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load external text file with jquery `$.get` api.

```
var fileUrl = '/file.html';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(fileUrl, function(data) {
        var fileDom = $(data);
        fileDom.find('< !--delete bellow this line-->').each(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

and Javascript cannot write to a file but you can try [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) plugin for saving content.